# How do I make my background fixed in Chrome?

Tags: css

On a site I am working on I have a background image that I want to must fill 100% width & 100% height of the browser & be fixed.. The below code works in ie10 & firefox 23 but does not work in Chrome (the background is not fixed - it scrolls).

Live Demo: http://ridge.mydevelopmentserver.com/

```
<div id="mainContent" class="bg1">my content</div>

#mainContent {
height: auto;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
color:#777777;
padding:20px;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

.bg1 {
background:url(../images/backgrounds/bg1.jpg)  no-repeat center center fixed;   
}
```

Anyone know how to make the background fixed in Chrome?

Thanks :)

Comment: By using the general `background` property, you are overwriting all properties that you don’t give an explicit value for with their default – looks like the browsers differ on whether `background-size` is included by the general `background` or not. Try giving the properties you are setting for `.bg1` separate (`background-url`, `background-repeat`, …), or move some of the “common” ones you don’t want to change with that selector up to `#mainContent`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add position fixed to .bg1 with left,top,right and bottom zero and do not forget **overflow-y: scroll;**

```
.bg1 {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: url(../images/backgrounds/bg1.jpg);
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    }
```

Comment: I changed the overflow to "overflow: auto;" so it scrolls both ways (if scrolling is required) & this works great - thankyou!